# docker-compose: can't specify nginx config

Tags: nginx, docker-compose

I'm trying to setup an nginx container via docker-compose. I have a custom configuration I'd like to use. I make the config available on a volume that is shared with the container.

```
nginx:
      volumes:
      - shared:/shared
      image: nginx
      ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "443:443"
      command: /bin/bash -c ./shared/nginx_test.conf
```

Here is the configuration file:

```
daemon off;

http {
    server {
    location / {
        root /shared/data/www;
    }

    location /images/ {
        root /data;
    }
    }
}
```

When I do a docker-compose up, I get errors for each line in the config that say the command is not found. e.g. `./shared/nginx_test.conf: line 1: daemon: command not found`, `./shared/nginx_test.conf: line 3: http: command not found` and so on.

I tried following the guide [here](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/nginx). Any ideas on why the commands are not found by nginx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to run a script file with `bash -c`, do you see that? That's not what you want. (The error messages say the content of `./shared/nginx_test.conf` is not understood, which Bash interprets as terminal commands.)

You probably want to run something like `nginx -g daemon off` as a command, and append the configuration file as an argument:

```
nginx:
    # ...
    command: nginx -c ./shared/nginx_test.conf -g "daemon off;"
```

References:

- [NGINX command line options](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/commandline/)
- [Bash man page](http://www.manpages.info/linux/bash.1.html)

Comment: Ahh, I think I got confused by this line from their docker doc. `command: /bin/bash -c "envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/mysite.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"` I'll try out your suggestion soon.